# how can I show the order of list's elements in python?

Tags: python, c, for-loop

In c, c++ when we say

```
For i=0 ;i<10 ;i++
Printf(i)
```

It prints the order used in the iretation 0,1,2...
but in python I have this example :

```
friends = ['Joseph', 'Glenn', 'Sally']
for friend in friends:
    print('Happy New Year:', friend)
```

I want to print the oder of the elements, Joseph is 0, Glenn is 1.. Etc, i know i can use a count=count+1 to print it, but I see print order knows already the order of elements, so is there a way similar to c to print the order of elements directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest analog to a C-style for loop is to use [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to use an index for a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) rather than element by element iteration:

```
friends = ['Joseph', 'Glenn', 'Sally']
for i in range(0,len(friends)):
    print(i, friends[i])
```

Prints:

```
0 Joseph
1 Glenn
2 Sally
```

With `range` you can set the start point, end point and step values (which can be positive or negative) just like a C for loop.

So you can go backwards as well (admittedly, not as elegant as C):

```
for i in range(len(friends)-1,-1,-1):
    print(i, friends[i])
2 Sally
1 Glenn
0 Joseph
```

As others have said, you can also use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to create a tuple of index, element from a sequence:

```
for t in enumerate(friends):
    print(t)

(0, 'Joseph')
(1, 'Glenn')
(2, 'Sally')
```

Which can be unpacked into two variables:

```
for idx, name in enumerate(friends):
    print(idx, name)
```

Prints:

```
0 Joseph
1 Glenn
2 Sally
```

---

Ultimately, C style for loops are a fancy form of while loop with an entry value, a tested value to end the loop and a function to update the loop value.

You can write a Python generator with this same behavior.

Suppose you have a list of tuples that you wish to navigate until the last value in the tuple is -1 (similar to a linked list...)

```
li=[(1,3),(2,5),(7,1),(18,2),(22,2),(-1,-1)]
```

You can write a generator like so:

```
def cfor(i, test_i, update_i):
    while test_i(i):
        yield i
        i=update_i(i)
```

And then use `lambda` functions test if you have reached your final condition:

```
for i in cfor(0,lambda i: li[i][1]!=-1, lambda i: li[i][1]):
    print(li[i])
```

Prints:

```
(1, 3)
(18, 2)
(7, 1)
(2, 5) # tuple at index 5 is (_,-1) which terminates the loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `enumerate` function to get the index of items in a list:

```
for idx, friend in enumerate(friends):
    print('Happy New Year:', idx, friend)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for index, friend in enumerate(friends):
    print(friend, " is ", index)
```

To learn more read [this](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate:

```
friends = ['Joseph', 'Glenn', 'Sally']
for i, friend in enumerate(friends):
    print(f"{friend} is {i}")
```

Output:

```
Joseph is 0
Glenn is 1
Sally is 2
```